# How do I tackle the error: A class declaration must have a body, even if it is empty?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in dart ,trying to complete the following task:
*Create a program that asks the user to enter their name and their age. Print out a message that tells how many years they have to be 100 years old.*

```
import 'dart:io';
void main(){
  print("Enter u'r name .");
  String? name=stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Enter u'r age.");
  int? number=stdin.readLineSync();
  var Count=count(name,number);
}

class count(){
  count(this.name,this.number);
  counter=100-number;
  print("$name,$counter years to live until 100!" );
}
```

and here's the error messages showing after I run the code, and I am wondering what has gone wrong, can someone give me a hint,thx.

```
 dart main.dart
main.dart:10:7: Error: A class declaration must have a body, even if it is empty.
Try adding an empty body.
class count(){
      ^^^^^
main.dart:10:12: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '('.
class count(){
           ^
main.dart:10:13: Error: Expected a declaration, but got ')'.
class count(){
            ^
main.dart:10:14: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '{'.
class count(){
             ^
main.dart:7:18: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
  var Count=count(name,number);
                 ^
main.dart:10:7: Context: The class 'count' has a constructor that takes no arguments.
class count(){
      ^
main.dart:6:21: Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int?'.
  int? number=stdin.readLineSync();
                    ^
exit status 254
```

Comment: `class count() {` should be `class count {`.

Answer (score 3):

The class needed to define as `class ClassName{}`

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print("Enter u'r name .");
  String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Enter u'r age.");
  int? number = stdin.readLineSync() as int?;

  // if we get null pass default value, you can also return

  Count count = Count(name ?? "default", number ?? 0);
  count.printResult();
}

class Count {
  final String name;
  final int number;

  Count(this.name, this.number) {
    // printResult(); // you can also direct print here
  }

  printResult() {
    int counter = 100 - number;
    print("$name,$counter years to live until 100!");
  }
}
```

More about dart-class on [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#instance-variables).

Comment: Also I would suggest not using class for counting. Counting years to 100 should be separate function and should be not connected with the name, cause couting years does not need name